# How do I implement an automatic session destroy and redirect after a certain inactivity period (Securely!)

Tags: php

What I mean by securely is the user doesn't need to refresh the page for the session to be destroyed. Simply idling should redirect and destroy the session. This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes), which I've already implemented the code from. However, it requires the user to refresh the page or some javascript/jquery to refresh it for them. However, isn't that not secure as **anyone** can change the javascript running on their browser client? This is my current code:

```
<?php
require('config.php');
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 10)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_destroy();
    header('LOCATION: login.php');
    session_write_close();
    exit;
}
$_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp

if (!isset($_SESSION['CREATED'])) {
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time();
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['CREATED'] > 10) {
    // session started more than 30 minutes ago
    session_regenerate_id(true); // change session ID for the current session and invalidate old session ID
    $_SESSION['CREATED'] = time(); // update creation time
}


if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {

    //Do my stuff and show the data to be secured

} else {
    echo "Forbidden";
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: When you say "security" what exact attack vector are you protecting against?

Comment: @zerkms A lot of modern websites will automatically close your session and redirect you after a period of inactivity. Currently, my webpage, if left untouched, will always be displaying vulnerable info (until a refresh). However, forcing a refresh seems to always use html or js, which can be edited client-side, so the vulnerable data is never removed from the screen. I hope that clarifies my question. If it doesn't just let me know.

Comment: It does not: "A lot of modern websites will automatically close your session and redirect you after a period" --- so what? What problem do **you** solve? What's a problem with a session that outlives the 30 minutes limit? "so the vulnerable data is never removed from the screen" --- if you served something to the client you don't have control over it.

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks so much.